# ArduinoJSON v6 - Passing buffer as function parameter

Tags: pointer, json

I'm new to ArduinoJSON - so perhaps it is a newbie's question.... but I wish to pass a `StaticJsonDocument` into a function as a parameter ( later on it should be implemented in a library ).

exmaple below shows `test_1` what I wish to obtain, but by duplicating `StaticJsonDocument`, which I don't want to do.

How can `test_1` should be written (as I tried in `test_2`)?

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;

void createJSON() {
        doc["sensor"] = "gps";
        doc["time"] = 1351824120;

        JsonArray data = doc.createNestedArray("data");
        data.add(48.756080);
        data.add(2.302038);

        // Generate the minified JSON and send it to the Serial port.
        serializeJson(doc, Serial);
        Serial.println("JSON is created:");

        // Generate the prettified JSON and send it to the Serial port.
        serializeJsonPretty(doc, Serial);

}


bool test_1(StaticJsonDocument<100> _doc){
        serializeJson(_doc, Serial);
        return true;
}

bool test2(const JsonObject& _doc){
        Serial.println("HI");
        serializeJson(_doc, Serial);
}


void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);

        createJSON();
        test_1(doc);


}

void loop() {
        // not used in this example
}
```

Comment: `bool test_1(StaticJsonDocument<DOC_SIZE>& _doc) {` use a define or const for the size. it must be the same

Comment: @Juraj - why not posting it as an answer ? it works OK

Comment: it is not about Arduino, but OK. I even found a better solution. (I know it is working, I tested it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `StaticJsonDocument` is a template class. The template value in <> is here only the size of the internal buffer, but every size used generates a different class. (memory usage!)

To have the parameter of the function take an `StaticJsonDocument` version instance, it must be the same version or a common base class. In this case the base class is `JsonDocument`.

If you don't use the reference symbol `&` the parameter is copied. In this case `StaticJsonDocument<200> _doc` or `JsonDocument _doc` would create a copy and that copy would be modified in the function. The object used as parameter value would be unchanged - empty.

So use

```
void test2(const JsonDocument& _doc) {
  Serial.println("HI");
  serializeJson(_doc, Serial);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Juraj, thanks for this answer. I'm trying to do exactly the same thing as @Guy .D, except when implementing your solution I'm getting a compiler error: 

`no known conversion for argument 2 from ArduinoJson6101_000::StaticJsonDocument<168u>' to 'const JsonObject& {aka const ArduinoJson6101_000::ObjectRef&}`  Any advice would be great and I can post a code snippet if required.

Comment: yes I'm using ArduinoJSON V6.

Comment: sorry, the code snippet was from Guy's code, not from my test. corrected